# Ether.li Wallet lost?

Tags: wallets, ether, recovery, ether.li

I created a Ether.li wallet but missed to press the finish button on the page where you note your keys.

Then i transferred money to the wallet which was not saved. After i got on the Ether.li hompage again to access the wallet it created a new wallet :(

I have all the Keys of the old wallet but cant recreate it.

I treid the following: https://www.masonborda.com/etherli-wallet-recoveries/
But there is nothing where i can past the ABI?!

Comment: You have backups of the keys? Did the import into geth work?

Comment: Yes the import work. i have a wallet based on the import

Comment: So you are stuck at the last step?